# HorizontalScrollView увеличивает длину окна диалога

Tags: android-dialog, horizontalscrollview

У меня есть кастомное диалоговое окно. Внутри него есть `HorizontalScrollView`, внутри которого есть `TextView`, текст которого динамически изменяется.

Когда текста мало, то ширина окна как у обычного диалога. Когда текста добавляется, то вместо того, чтобы работала прокрутка увеличивается ширина диалогового окна.

Как запретить такое поведение? Полдня на это убил, видимо в Андроиде это невозможно сделать или я не прав?

Answer (score 0):

Решение, к сожалению, только одно: не использовать `HorizontalScrollView` в диалогах. Это недоработки в самом рендеринге Андроид.